# MySQL, get a sum from column after grouped by another column

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I have a DB table `votes` that looks like

```
|   id   |  val   |   against_id   |   created_at   |
-----------------------------------------------------
A        |  1     |     B          |  xxx
B        | -1     |     A          |  xxx
C        |  1     |     B          |  xxx
B        | -1     |     C          |  xxx
...
```

For each "vote" there are 2 rows.

I want to get a result that lists every `id` distinctly with the `sum()` of `val`, like:

```
| id  |  score  |
-----------------
A     |   42    |
B     |   5     |
C     |   -15   |
D     |   150   |
```

Is there an equivalent of `foreach` in mysql?

Comment: For the sample data you have given, what would be the desired output?

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't that clear but have you tried a simple, SUM/GROUP BY?

```
SELECT ID, SUM(Score) FROM MyTable GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: This is exactly it. I knew it was simple and was getting tripped up with distinct. Thanks!